# Set Textbox side by side

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have set textboxes created dynamically I would like to show side by side instead of show one below the other.

```
<div class="wrap-login100 p-l-20 p-t-25">
        <form class="form" name="add_name" id="add_name">
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="inc">
                    <div class="testing">
                            
                            <div class="form-group col-md-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Enter Manger First Name" > 
                                <div id="error" style="display:none; color: red;">Enter First Name before submission!</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-10">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Enter Manager Last Name" >
                                <div id="error2" style="display:none; color: red;">Enter Last Name before submission!</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-10">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="append" name="append">
                            Add Team Details</button>
                            </div>
                          <br>
                          <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10 text-center">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="submit" name="submit" value="Register"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

[image]

This is perfect but when I create the textbox dynamically I want it to side by side. instead of this:

[image]

Here is the dynamic text box code:

```
<script>
var counter=0;
jQuery(document).ready( function () 
{
    
    $("#append").click( function(e) 
    {
        counter++;
          e.preventDefault();
        $(".inc").append('<div class="testing">\
                <div class="form-group col-md-10">TE - ' +counter+ '</div>\
                <div class="form-group col-md-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tename[]" id="tename"  placeholder="Enter TE Name"> </div>\
                <div class="form-group col-md-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="hq[]" id="hq"  placeholder="Enter HQ"></div> \
                <div class="form-group col-md-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="state[]" id="state"  placeholder="Enter State"> </div>\
                <div class="form-group col-md-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="department[]" id="department"  placeholder="Department"> </div>\
                <div class="form-group col-md-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="teamno[]" id="teamno"  placeholder="Enter team number"> </div>\
                <div class="form-group col-md-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="leadname[]" id="leadname"  placeholder="Enter Lead Name"></div>\
                <div class="form-group col-md-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="holiday[]" id="holiday"  placeholder="Numbers of holidays entire week"></div>\
                <div class="form-group col-md-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="offpermonth[]" id="offpermonth"  placeholder="Off Per month"></div>\
                <div class="form-group col-md-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lop[]" id="lop"  placeholder="LOP Details"></div>\
                <a href="#" class="remove_this btn btn-danger btn-lg">Remove</a>\
                <br>\
                <br>\
            </div>');
        return false;
        });

    jQuery(document).on('click', '.remove_this', function() {
        jQuery(this).parent().remove();
        counter--;
        return false;
        });
    $('#submit').click(function()
    {
      var textBox = $("#amname").val();
      var textBox2 = $("#rmname").val();
      
        if (textBox == "")
        {
            $("#error").show('slow');
        }
        else if (textBox2 == "")
        {
            $("#error2").show('slow');
        }
        else
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"savedata.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:$('#add_name').serialize(),
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alert(data);
                    //window.location.replace("lobby.php");
                    
                }
            });
        }
    })
    
});
```

How do I go about it doing it?

Comment: Looks like each of the text boxes are wrapped in `col-md-10` meaning they will take 10 col space out of 12 and push the next element in new line. Other thing is the use of `form-control` class, it will make control to use full width available. One thing you could do is to redesign your form and use `col-md-6` so you could have 2 side by side or change the column styling as per the need. You may have to use a wrapper div as `row`. Probably give `row` class to `div.testing`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: inline-block` is your friend. Add new class or give `form-group` css like below.

```js
var counter = 1;
$(".inc").append('<div class="testing">\
                <div class="form-group col-md-10">TE - ' + counter + '</div>\
                <div class="form-group col-md-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tename[]" id="tename"  placeholder="Enter TE Name"> </div>\
                <div class="form-group col-md-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="hq[]" id="hq"  placeholder="Enter HQ"></div> \
                <div class="form-group col-md-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="state[]" id="state"  placeholder="Enter State"> </div>\
                <div class="form-group col-md-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="department[]" id="department"  placeholder="Department"> </div>\
                <div class="form-group col-md-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="teamno[]" id="teamno"  placeholder="Enter team number"> </div>\
                <div class="form-group col-md-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="leadname[]" id="leadname"  placeholder="Enter Lead Name"></div>\
                <div class="form-group col-md-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="holiday[]" id="holiday"  placeholder="Numbers of holidays entire week"></div>\
                <div class="form-group col-md-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="offpermonth[]" id="offpermonth"  placeholder="Off Per month"></div>\
                <div class="form-group col-md-10"> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lop[]" id="lop"  placeholder="LOP Details"></div>\
                <a href="#" class="remove_this btn btn-danger btn-lg">Remove</a>\
                <br>\
                <br>\
            </div>');
```

```css
div.form-group {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inc"></div>
```

Comment: <style>
  div.form-group {
   display: inline-block
 }
 </style>

I tried this but didn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try with important, looks like some css override.    `div.form-group { display: inline-block !important; }`

Comment: still the same :(

Comment: Or give new class with css.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a read once

https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-float-three-div-side-by-side-using-css/amp/

Has 3 ways, I have tried the table method mentioned and that worked for me.

Way to put three div side by side by using display property.

- **display:table**; This property is used for elements (div) which behaves like table.
- **display:table-cell**; This property is used for elements (div) which behaves like td.
- **display:table-row** This property is used for elements (div) which behaves like tr.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>  
    <head>  
      
        <!-- CSS style to place three div side by side -->
        <style>  
            .container .box {  
                width:540px;  
                margin:50px;  
                display:table;  
            }  
            .container .box .box-row {  
                display:table-row;  
            }  
            .container .box .box-cell {  
                display:table-cell;  
                width:33%;  
                padding:10px;  
            }  
            .container .box .box-cell.box1 {  
                background:green;  
                color:white;  
                text-align:justify;  
            }  
            .container .box .box-cell.box2 {  
                background:lightgreen;  
                text-align:justify  
            }  
            .container .box .box-cell.box3 {  
                background:lime;  
                text-align:justify;  
            } 
        </style>  
    </head>  
      
    <body>  
        <center> 
        <h1 style = "color:green;">GeeksforGeeks</h1>  
        <div class="container">  
            <div class="box">  
                <div class="box-row">  
                    <div class="box-cell box1">  
                        It is a good platform to learn programming. 
                        It is an educational website. Prepare for 
                        the Recruitment drive of product based 
                        companies like Microsoft, Amazon, Adobe etc 
                        with a free online placement preparation  
                        course. 
                    </div>  
                      
                    <div class="box-cell box2">  
                        The course focuses on various MCQ's & 
                        Coding question likely to be asked in 
                        the interviews & make your upcoming 
                        placement season efficient and successful.  
                    </div>  
                      
                    <div class="box-cell box3">  
                        Any geeks can help other geeks by writing 
                        articles on the GeeksforGeeks, publishing 
                        articles follow few steps that are Articles 
                        that need little modification/improvement 
                        from reviewers are published first. 
                    </div>  
                </div>  
            </div>  
        </div>  
        </center> 
    </body>  
</html>
```